# When to use property delegation and when to use property getter in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

With release of Kotlin 1.4, we can do [delegation of properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#delegating-to-another-property) as:

```kotlin
val delegatedProperty: Int by anotherObj::intProperty
```

But where are they useful? As when should somebody use them over the old-style getter and setter definitions?

```kotlin
val delegatedProperty: Int get() = anotherObj.intProperty
```

And even the this old-style getter/setter seems to have less performance impact than the new one (which seems to be based on Reflection).

So, on which purpose new property access delegation is better and on which purpose old-style property delegation is better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it to "pass through" the property of some other object more concisely.

```
class Foo (private val bar: Bar) {

    var barName by bar::name

}
```

versus

```
class Foo (private val bar: Bar) {

    var barName: String 
        get() = bar.name
        set(value) { bar.name = value }

}
```

Comment: In the cost of creating KProperty0 (reflection object) :'(